# In which part of the Sagnac fiber optic setup will the light undergo the most intense interference?

Tags: interference, fiber-optics

Let's assume we have a Sagnac setup consisting of a 1310nm laser, 2X2 coupler injecting light into two opposite ends of a single mode fiber loop, and a photodiode receiving the light from both ends of the fiber coupled into the same 2X2 coupler.

In which part of the setup will the light undergo the most intense interference: in the fiber loop, in the 2X2 coupler, or on the face of the photodiode?

```
                              Rotating Fiber Loop 
                             _____________________  
                             |                   |
                2X2 Coupler  |                   |
     Laser ---------||-------                    | 
Photodiode ---------||-------                    |
                             |                   |
                             |___________________|
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the most intense interference"?

Comment: @flippiefanus I mean the degree to which destructive, or constructive interference will occure which can be measured by the photodiode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only location where a measurement reading can be obtained at all is at the photodiode.

Compare the case of interference effect obtained with a double slit setup. Let's say the light that has passed throught the double slit falls on photosensitive film. After taking an image the film is developed, and the developed film shows interference fringes.

Can we say with certainty where in space that interference effect occurred?  
Propagating light will not interact with other light propagating through the same space.

(Actually, photon-photon scattering has a non-zero probability, but it's a very, very low probability, and the lower the frequency, the lower the probability.)

In the case of light interacting with a photosensitive material, it's that interaction that allows obtaining a measurement reading.

More philosophically:
Is the process of developing the photosensitive material an irreversible process, a point of no return? Or is it even the case that we must allow the possibility that the developed photosensitive material is in a superposition state of possible states, and that what we see with our eyes as we look at the developed film is one possibility out of an infinity of possibilities?

So:
The question: where does interference effect occur is far from straightforward.

It seems to me: in order to obtain a *measurement reading* the propagating light must interact with matter, being absorbed or transformed in the process.

Comment: The fact that you need to measure the interference to know its amount doesn't mean that physical effects of interference don't occur. Also, there are other methods of measuring interference without using a photodiode. So you answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jimski Let me illustrate my point with another example: use a beam splitter and mirrors to create from a single laser source two beams, such that they cross each other, but onto separate screens. Let me refer to the two beams as 'beam A' and 'beam B', and the respective screens 'screen A' and 'screen B'. The thing is: whether beam A is blocked or not will make no difference for the *propagation* of beam B, *all* of it will reach screen B, and vice versa for the propagation of beam A. However, it appears you believe there will be constructive/destructive interference, resulting in difference.

Comment: Two beams passing through a beam splitter are not the same as beams traveling thought a long fiber such as Sagnac loop, which polarizes the light and has defects and contaminats which must induce at least some interference, the amount of which I don't know. In some couplers the internal splices interact with light in many ways, ie. reflecting, polarizing, etc. so some interference must also occur in the coupler. So that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @Jimski On a physics forum like this (and in general in physics discourse) the default is to treat a presented setup as idealized case. The default is to treat optics as defect free and contaminant free. I recommend that you edit your question, stating specifically that you do want to consider defects and contaminants, and possible interaction effects (reflection, polarization) in the couplers

Comment: There is no such default in physics, particularly in the experimental physics where very poblems of purity and accuracy may affect experimental data.

Answer (score 1):

A "classical/historical" understanding of "interference" can lead to confusion.

Let's be modern about it (per Dirac/Feynman and others):

1. every photon acts on its own as dictated by the EM field.
2. photons never cancel each other, that is a violation of conservation of energy.
3. The excited atom/electron is already interacting virtually with the EM field long before photon emission.
4. Per Feynman path integral, photons will travel paths where path lengths that are multiples of the wavelength have the highest probability.
5. We can never observe superpositions in/of the EM-field/photons directly ... all detectors only absorb single photons one at a time.
6. In the double slit experiment "interferences" are where no energy goes (dark) and all energy goes (bright bands) .... the virtual EM field having guided all energy.

The implications of the above are that the observed "interferences" , i.e the CCD/photodiode will absorb all power emitted from the laser .... the observed rings are spatial "interferences", some areas bright and some dark. "Interference" takes place over the whole apparatus.

Interestingly we can turn off a laser from many meters away simply by placing a mirror in the beam path .... "interference" can extend over a large distance .... i.e the virtual EM field is active over large distances.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149196/discussion-on-answer-by-physicsdave-in-which-part-of-the-sagnac-fiber-optic-setu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.