# Spherical Electromagnetic Radiation Propagating Inwards

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics

Suppose I produce a large number of photons subject to the following conditions:

1. The photons are produced at (approximately) the same time at (approximately) the surface of a sphere (if I'm not mistaken, we can only talk about the expectation of these quantities and not absolutes when considering single-photon states).
2. Each photon's momentum is (approximately) directed towards the centre of the sphere.

So in other words, we're considering a large sphere of photons which are propagating "inwards" towards a common point. I'm assuming the total centre-of-mass energy is small enough that gravity is negligible.

My question is, neglecting gravitational effects, can we describe this situation in the classical limit (as the number/density of photons increases to infinity)?

If this is possible, what kind of classical solution to Maxwell's equations would I be looking for, in order to describe this situation?

If this is impossible, why does this situation require a quantum-theoretic description?

Comment: Why would you not just consider a spherical antenna? Especially, why not just ignore the photons that are directly away from the sphere rather than insist that you would only generate photons with momenta directed towards the centre? Spherical waves are somewhat a standard solution of Maxwell's equations, so I really do not know what it is you want?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent It's a thought experiment designed to help gain understanding about the correspondence principle, and the specific implications of the physical scenario presented. I think the conditions of the though experiment and the question itself is well-posed. If you think this question is well-answered using a spherical antenna, could you explain why please (in an answer perhaps?).

Comment: Wait a moment. I'm asking questions here precisely because I do not think your question is well-posed enough to be answered; what even does this problem have anything to do with the correspondence principle? I think you really need to clarify what it is you intended to get with this question, so that we can try to help you better. And as a general rule of thumb, thought experiments are something beginners should avoid. They are incredibly difficult to pose properly; Einstein is a genius and can do it effortlessly, but us mere mortals should not mimic that carelessly.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I think it's quite clear how "taking a limit as the number of quantum states goes to infinity" is connected to the correspondence principle. Please correct me if I've misunderstood the correspondence principle. I'm reading off https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the sources are a bunch of lasers directed at a common point (like they do at the National Ignition Facility at Lawrence Livermore lab).

Now let's remove the target (at the centre) and try to estimate what is happening with the EM field there ...

1. Classically we would have a bunch of photons arriving at mostly different phases (assuming path length differences on a wavelength scale) leading to an average zero E and M field .... everything cancels! BUT nothing could be further from the truth!
2. Logically what is really going to happen is the beams will continue on and be absorbed somewhere in the apparatus.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. However, if I'm not mistaken, lasers can't produce single-photon states, so (to me at least) they don't apply to the situation presented in the question. Please correct me if I'm wrong and if lasers do in fact help here. Also from your answer it's still not clear to me where the classical correspondence comes in (or doesn't as the case may be).

Comment: @JamieS your original question's wording said that you are perfectly fine with large numbers of photons; if you wanted a single photon, you should have worded it so.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The original question specified that the photons would be produced on the same sphere at around the same time. As far as I understand, lasers can't be understood as producing single photon states at a (roughly) well-defined moment of time, but rather as producing coherent photons in large numbers with less certainty about the time of emission of any particular photon. You're right that large numbers of photons are a part of the question, but it's the spacetime distribution of them that's also of interest.

Comment: @JamieS So let's assume we have precisely controlled single photon lasers ... classically the EM field will be huge assuming the sphere is an integer lambda size ... but after that instant they just re-emege as individual photons again.  If there was a target it would absorb photons one at a time, that's QM.

Comment: @JamieS more about light here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784292/in-which-part-of-the-sagnac-fiber-optic-setup-will-the-light-undergo-the-most-in/784356#784356

Comment: @PhysicsDave Can a "single-photon laser" exist? I've read that lasers operate by producing a superposition of different number states. Wouldn't that be contradictory with the idea of a single-photon laser?

Comment: @JamieS. single photon sources exist ... but as far as I know it's like having a baby i.e. timing is not precise. It could be laser like or similar to led.   Your original question is theoretical, I'm not sure how practical .... we never observe the EM field directly (i.e its superpositions) we only observe by absorbing one photon at a time .... in fact light is all created one photon at a time.  Water waves by contrast we can observe the superpositions .... 2 tsunamis can cancel momentarily but the waves would reemerge later ... the energy stored in the elasticity of the water.

Comment: @JamieS An ideal medium (water, EM field)never absorbs the energy .... waves need to crash on the shore .... photons need to be absorbed by atoms etc..

Comment: @PhysicsDave Thanks for your insights. I suppose I'm asking if there's any classical description that approximates a "sheet" of single-photon states converging on a single point, or if (conversely) one fundamentally needs to consider all individual photon states.

Comment: @JamieS Classically the waves add up which is correct .... but waves cancelling is misleading from a physics point of view .... that's a classical issue!  It is not discussed much in physics .... swept under the rug .... not considered important (but it is) ... too many math people in physics (this is good and bad).

Comment: @JamieS The EM field rules ... it can handle many photons or just one.

Comment: @PhysicsDave in that case, could you point me towards a solution to Maxwell's equations/ a resource that would help me find my own solution for this situation?

Comment: @JamieS One of Maxwell's most famous eqns is how light energy could travel as 2 perpendicular synced sinusoidal E and M waves ... very important.  You can add these waves classically but its after Maxwell that we have Dirac and Feynman trying to explain how "interferences" occur ...even then these guys had much more important things to do ... the nuclear age/nuclear physics/WWII.  As far as I know ... I have not seen the calculation you are trying to do .... i.e. perfect phase photons adding at a concentric point from a spherical angles ....

Comment: @JamieS. .... the net EM fields likely zero but the energy held in the "elasticity" of the EM field (my own term).