# Single-photon interferometry with fibers: the very first experiment

Tags: quantum-optics, interferometry

I am looking for the very first published experiment in a relevant journal with all the following features:

1. Michelson or Mach-Zender light interferometry is demonstrated
2. The arms of the interferometer are optical fibers
3. The light used is a slow sequence of single quanta (aka single-photons) generated with on-demand methods (e.g. Quantum dots).

Does anyone know the reference of this article?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited for the history of science and math stack exchange

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784292/in-which-part-of-the-sagnac-fiber-optic-setup-will-the-light-undergo-the-most-in.  This question is related ... it does not matter whether you have single photons or many photons .... the result is the same.